# What does int ** ptr (pointer to a pointer) as a C++ function argument mean?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameter-passing

I was asked to write a program that gets an array of integers `arr`, and its logical size. When called it creates a new array containing only the positive numbers from arr.
For example, if `arr=[3, -1, -3, 0, 6, 4]`, the functions should create an array containing the following 3 elements: `[3, 6, 4]`,

The specific function should be like this:

`void getPosNums4 (int* arr, int arrSize,`
`int** outPosArrPtr, int* outPosArrSizePtr)`
uses the pointer `outPosArrPtr` to update the base address of the array (containing the positive numbers), and the pointer `outPosArrSizePtr` to update the array’s logical size.

I was having difficulty understanding what does `** outPosArrPtr` mean, as well as how to use it in both the main function and the function call. I am aware that my main function's cout will be the address in the memory of the new array, as well as the new array's size. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

void getPosNums4(int* arr, int arrSize, int** outPosArrPtr, int* outPosArrSizePtr);

int main(){
    int arr[8]= {3,-1,-3,0,6,4,-5,8};
    int* inputPtr = arr;
    int inputArrSize = 8;

    int* outputArrSizePtr = new int;
    int outputArrSize = 0;
    outputArrSizePtr = &outputArrSize;

    int* outPosArr = new int[outputArrSize];
    int** outPosArrPtr = &outPosArr;
    cout<<"Test function 4: "<<endl;
    getPosNums4(inputPtr, inputArrSize, outPosArrPtr, outputArrSizePtr);
    cout<<outPosArrPtr<<*outputArrSizePtr4<<endl;
    return 0;
}


void getPosNums4(int* arr, int arrSize, int** outPosArrPtr, int* outPosArrSizePtr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
        if (arr[i] > 0){
            *outPosArrPtr[*outPosArrSizePtr] = arr[i];
            *outPosArrSizePtr = *outPosArrSizePtr + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Globally, this is a "C-syntax", not a "C++-syntax". If you're writing your own code, I highly suggest you to move to standard containers like `std::vector`, references and smart pointers instead of bare pointers. You probably can't imagine how much mess you can make with bare pointers... And if you can't do otherwise (because of a library, for example), then encapsulate that ASAP and avoid giving bare pointers everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

`int** outPosArrPtr` is a pointer array, or alternatively a pointer to pointers. This is a common concept in C and I recommend *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie for further details.

To understand what's going on, first let's just look at the simpler *pointer-to-int*:

`int *outPosArrPtr`

In C, this *pointer-to-int* can be equivalent to an *integer array*:

`int outPosArrPtr[]`

But what about the second `*`?

-This means you have a *pointer-to-pointer-to-int*, which you **can** use as an array of pointers-to-int.
So the function `void getPosNums4` itself does *not* create a new array that contains only positive numbers. Instead, it returns a pointer array with pointers that point to the memory location of only the positive numbers in the original input array `int *arr`.